# Entity Framework modify models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to modify the model entity which is sent to the **CreateEmployee Method** as a parameter to be modified.

```
public void CreateEmployee(string roleName, EmployeeModel emp)
{
    string roleName == "user";
    emp.Roles.Select(e => new RoleModel { RoleName = roleName });
    AddEmployee(emp);
}
```

this is how models looks like....
[image]

And it give me an error saying

> Model does not contain a definition for 'Select' and 'Select' accepting a first argument of type Model could be found....

I have tried using the 'Where' method as well, but still give the same error..

```
emp.Roles.Where(e => e.RoleName == roleName)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in your code,

1. use `=` not `==` for assignment
2. the selected roles does not used
3. Linq query functions like `Select` and `Where` apply to `IEnumerable` the `Roles` property is of type `RoleModel` not `IEnumerable<RoleModel>`

so:

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    //some code
    public ICollection<RoleModel> Roles{ get; set; }
}


using System.Linq;

public void CreateEmployee(string roleName, EmployeeModel emp)
{
   string roleName = "user";
   var empRoles = emp.Roles.Select(e => new RoleModel { RoleName = roleName });
   AddEmployee(emp);
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to have one role per employee at most, the relationship between `Role` and `Employee` became one-to-many(each role has n employee)
if `Role` is optional for employee:

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    //some code
    public short? RoleId { get; set; }//nullable foreign key
    public virtual RoleModel { get; set; } //Navigation property
}
public class RoleModel
{
    //some code
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees{ get; set; }
}
```

But, if `Role` is required for `Employee` you must change the foreign key to:

```
    public short RoleId { get; set; }//non-null foreign key
```

For getting an `Employee`'s `Role` you do not need to use `Select` or `Where` on navigation property, just use `employee.Role`.

Finally for querying `Role`'s employees you can use `Select`, `Where`, ... as mentioned before.

Comment: Thank you for the help.... when i changed my RoleModel to ICollection model error was gone... but is there anyway that i can just use RoleModel instead of a Icollection?... because i just need to insert one Role value here